# Feature In A Poker Game

Tags: texas-hold-em, strategy

I am going to build a stand alone (not web) poker game / training tool where you play against 5 bots for a 6 player SNG format.  Will put in one fish, one rock, and 3 GTO based bots that have slightly different starting ranges but other than that play exactly the same.  With each new game you don't know what seat they are in.

If the user wants to turn on help it will even tell them number of outs, pot odds, and hand odds.

If you were going to track every statistic you could ever want what would you want to track?

This is my starting list

- $ plus minus by position
- every hand by position with (just as rank rank and if suited)
  count of win lose fold
  net $
- pre flop by position
  open #
  open avg
  call #
  raise # and avg raise
  3 bet # and avg
  (probably going to cap it at 3 bet as too much logic for the bots)
  fold # and avg raise the fold faced (as ratio to the pot?)
- turn same as pre flop
  add number of donks
- river same as pre flop

For the bots I can report number of bluffs but I don't really know if the hero was bluffing.

I want this to be an application I can port to a phone which is one reason for 6 seats.  But that could change.  What I am more asking for here is what type of statistics you would like reported.

Comment: I am a decent developer and I can tell you this is harder than I thought.  Just moving the button, dealing, taking bets, and deciding who won is a lot of logic.  The bots themselves is the easier part.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

- Save everything to a database so you can write whatever kind of query you want about a hand.
- make the number of bots from one to nine rather just five.
- Let the player change the seats of particular robots
- Let the player decide the texture of the bots, rather then forcing them to play with a set number of aggressive bots
- let the player replay the hand, from a different table configuration if they choose.
- Let players write their own bots for the simulation.
- Repeat save all the data possible then see what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The plan for now is 6 player SNG format for simplicity and I think it is a good format for learning the game.  I am a database developer but I don't want to use a database.  I want it to be a very light weight app that I could port to a phone but it would be cool if they could have a history of all their hands. They are not aggressive bots.  Two fish.  GTO is not necessarily aggressive.